# Use the same phrase in different context?

Tags: phrase-usage

The plot of the movie "X-Men: Days of Future Past" provided by [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Days_of_Future_Past) gives enough data for us to infer that for the time traveller who has gone back in time, the days of the future are in their past; hence the name "Days of Future Past".

Can I use this same title ("Days of Future Past") to mean days without outlook of the future, using the word "past" to mean "no longer", of course giving the right context to it?

Comment: You could try to use the title that way, but I don't think anyone would understand it without explanation. Also: the plot **gives** **data** for us to **infer**.

Answer (score 2):

No. The title of the movie 'Days of Future Past' is not a known phrase or idiom that makes any logical sense. The future is not the past. It only makes any sense in connection with the fictional concept of time-travel, which is a central premise to the movie.

The film took the title from a 1981 X-Men comic story '*Days of Future Past*', which in turn was a pun on the title of the 1967 album '*Days of Future Passed*' by The Moody Blues. The record is a concept album about the life of an everyday man, so the title was not meant to suggest anything to do with time travel.

Comment: How would you explain the meaning of: "Days of Future Passed" in context of The Moody Blues album?